# Is it possible to use keep-alive with boost::beast sync https client?

Tags: c++, boost, https, boost-asio, boost-beast

Is it possible to use http 1.1 keep-alive with the boost beast library when using a sync ssl client?  I have a process that works something like this:

1. Connection to web server using https.  Send an initial request, wait for a response
2. select()/epoll()/etc on the https native socket handle
3. When the native handle has something ready, I issue an http::read() on the `ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>`.

The first http::read() works perfectly fine.  However, when the socket is ready the next time, I get an end of stream exception when issuing an http::read() on the socket.  What I want is for the socket to stay alive for multiple requests.

The code isn't too complicated, but it's in pieces:

```
         if( native_socket_for_https_connection_ready ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
              boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::dynamic_body> res;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
              boost::beast::http::read( m_HTTPSConnection, m_HTTPSBuffer, res, ec );                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              std::cout << "Https Connection Response: " << res << std::endl;                                                                                                                              
              std::cout << "Keep-Alive Result: " << res.keep_alive() << std::endl;                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              m_HTTPSBuffer.clear();                                                                                                                                                                       
          }
```

Where, `m_HTTPSConnection` is a `boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream>`, and `m_HTTPSBuffer` is a `flat_buffer`.  The only other detail is the extraction of the native socket.

I am trying to fit reading from a secure socket into a legacy application that is not using async I/O -- I want the subsequent reads on http::read() to complete and not throw an exception.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Did you request a persistent connection when you made the request? How long is the wait between requests? Are you sure it's not the server dropping the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server could be dropping the connection, e.g. when your request maybe of indeterminate content-length, making it impossible to keep the connection open (how would the server know that the request was incomplete?).

So, just imagining some more complete code:

1a. connection to web server using https

```
ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> s(ioc, ctx);
s.next_layer().connect({address_v4{{34, 227, 133, 25}}, 443});
s.handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);
```

1b. send an initial request

```
http::request<http::string_body> req(http::verb::post, "/post", 10,
                                     R"~({"data":42})~");
req.set(http::field::host, "httpbin.org");
req.keep_alive(true); // no difference on HTTP/1.1+
req.prepare_payload();
write(s, req);
```

2. Then wait for a response (select/epoll):

```
std::future<void> ready = s.next_layer().socket().async_wait(
    net::socket_base::wait_type::wait_read, net::use_future);
ready.wait();
```

> *(obviously, this can be done by external code based on the `native_handle()` instead)*

3. Issue read on the stream

```
http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;
beast::flat_buffer                 buf;
http::read(s, buf, res);
```

It all works nicely:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2f4e2478d335b42)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
namespace ssl   = net::ssl;
using boost::system::error_code;
using net::ip::address_v4;
using net::ip::tcp;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
static auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;

int main() {
    net::thread_pool ioc;

    // connection to web server using https
    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> s(ioc, ctx);
    s.next_layer().connect({address_v4{{34, 227, 133, 25}}, 443});
    s.handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);

    for (auto demo_end = now() + 1s; now() <= demo_end; sleep_for(10ms)) {
        // send an initial request
        http::request<http::string_body> req(http::verb::post, "/post", 10,
                                             R"~({"data":42})~");
        req.set(http::field::host, "httpbin.org");
        req.keep_alive(true); // no difference on HTTP/1.1+
        req.prepare_payload();
        write(s, req);

        // wait for a response
        // (obviously, this can be done by external code based on the
        // native_handle() instead)
        std::future<void> ready = s.next_layer().socket().async_wait(
            net::socket_base::wait_type::wait_read, net::use_future);
        ready.wait();

        // issue read on the stream
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;
        beast::flat_buffer                 buf;
        http::read(s, buf, res);

        std::cout << "Https Connection Response: " << res << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Keep-Alive Result: " << res.keep_alive() << std::endl;
        if (!res.keep_alive())
            break;
    }

    // bye
    ioc.join();
}
```

Prints

```
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00a-124910e0751e35dd54340615"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00a-5fa263b33e2cc5937d6204a5"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00a-0430cdac1b7924210e9ea13d"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00a-7683e03c727619fc5e5db850"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00a-5c733376197f2e0d68afb4c8"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00a-604db5aa0f4abccc4c721740"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00a-3ea4400e52caa293041cd83f"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-05d2949e37556119199d2627"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-57e377492da2d9f26c205699"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-526a207d11c3aa9d231ec537"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-64f2d0df238d5d14388390db"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-1612613c2520b2a908706e58"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-00d80af2769dbc023e8ab652"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-505398b91878748a45d04795"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-087616e737a56957076e0a9c"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-31987540136993062764c373"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-37efb18d7fdc07ef1d4051cf"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-666c753e62ff049e375253d3"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-524b4fea230a31273a1264e6"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-4352dd83652fa4d74d8910e8"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1
Https Connection Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2022 16:42:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 321
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"data\":42}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6220f00b-36f9eb3918e3fbf215e0c5a7"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "data": 42
  }, 
  "origin": "173.203.57.63", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

Keep-Alive Result: 1

This file can be also found using the Coliru command line: cat /Archive2/c2/f4e2478d335b42/main.cpp
```

Comment: Note I used HTTP/1.0 just to demonstrate the keep-alive header. If you use HTTP/1.1 it will simply omit the header but still work as desired: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/169f7fc8d97215cd

Comment: I'll mark this answer as correct once I try my code on this https URL.  In your code, you keep issuing requests.  In mine, I wait until the need arises to send a request.  However, after the first http::read(), select says I have data, and then the http::read effectively terminates.  I'm going to target the same URL as you and see how it goes.  I appreciate this sample a great deal.

Comment: "In your code, you keep issuing requests. In mine, I wait until the need arises to send a request." - You could say that is exactly the same. My demo "waits until the need arises as well". It happens to be in 10ms.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the model for keep-alive that your example very clearly illuminated.  I can't just "sit around"; I have to constantly post.  My code worked perfectly fine just changing to your URL.  I'll just have to go back to my other server service point and try to be more aggressive with their timing window.

Comment: You have to keep in mind the connection is *always* at the discretion of the server. The same way they are free to refuse a connection, they might terminate one at their convenience. There are additional headers that can sometimes be used by the server to indicate the keep-alive parameters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive but again, no rights can be derived from that.
Perhaps your server has a websocket interface as well, which is more commonly long-lived.